# Difficulty with counts

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of encounters (relevant column names: enc_id (guid) and enc_nbr (int))
I have a table of encounter_notes (enc_id (guid))

I want to generate a list of enc_nbr where the related enc_id shows up in encounter_notes 10 times or more.

What I have tried:

```
select count(*) from encounters 
where enc_id in (select count(enc_id) from encounter_notes having count(enc_id)>9)
```

This gives the following error:

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Comment: enc_id is a guid(uniqueidentifier), count(enc_id_) is a number. you can't compare a number and a guid directly. try:  select enc_id from encounter_notes group by end_id having count(enc_id)>9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare between a `guid` and a `number`.

You can also use `CTE` to achieve it.

```
;WITH cte AS
  (SELECT enc_id,
          count(enc_id)
   FROM encounter_notes
   GROUP BY enc_id
   HAVING count(enc_id)>9)
SELECT *
FROM encounters e
INNER JOIN cte ON e.enc_id = cte.enc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 
    enc_id
    ,NumberOfOccurances = COUNT(*) 
FROM ENCOUNTERS
GROUP BY enc_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 9
```

The `HAVING` clause allows you to put a filter on an aggregate function, which you can't do with a `WHERE` clause. This query will return each `enc_id` and how many times it occurs, for all `enc_id` values that occur more than 9 times.

EDIT:

If you just want your code to run, you could change it to this:

```
select count(*) 
from encounters 
where enc_id in (select enc_id from encounter_notes having count(enc_id)>9)
```

Your subquery should return the set of GUIDs (`enc_id`) instead of the number of different values. But this isn't really good code. If possible, you should avoid subqueries in your `WHERE` clause like this, because the subquery ends up getting executed for every record in your outer query. This takes a long time.